# How can I compare with a single apostrophe in SQL to see if a column starts with an apostrophe?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Basically I am trying to trim the left-most character if and only if it as an apostrophe.

My script is as follows

```
Identifier =
    CASE
        WHEN LEFT(Identifier, 1) = '' -- I think this is wrong
            THEN RIGHT(Identifier, LEN(Identifier) - 1) ELSE Identifier
        END,
```

What I want to do is remove the first character if and only if it is an apostrophe but I don't know how to perform the comparison with the single quote.

This is in SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
LEFT(Identifier, 1) = ''''
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
when left(identifier, 1) = ''''
```